# How to print the result of the first part of the pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, xargs

I have the following grep:

```
grep -Po '(?<=PROGRAM\()[^\)]+(?=\))' /home/programs/hello_word.sh
```

Wich displays the string between `PROGRAM(` and `)`:

```
RECTONTER
```

Then, I need to know if these string extracted is contained in a file, so:

```
grep -Po '(?<=PROGRAM\()[^\)]+(?=\))' /home/programs/hello_word.sh | xargs -I % grep -e % /home/leherad/pgm_currentdate
```

File content:

```
RECTONTER
CORASFE
RENTOASD
UBICARP
```

If its found, returns the line of /home/leherad/pgm_currentdate, but I want to print the line extracted in the first grep (`RECTONTER`). If not found, then wouldn't return nothing.

There is a simple way to do this, or I should not complicate and would be better build a script and save the first grep in a variable?

Comment: This is some that `awk` may be able to handle in one go.  If you post your files and desired output, we may be able to help.

Comment: Did you look into the [$PIPESTATUS](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another) variable ?

Comment: Use the tee command ?

Comment: You mean something like this? `grep -Po '(?<=PROGRAM\()[^\)]+(?=\))' /home/programs/hello_word.sh | xargs -I % grep -e % /home/leherad/pgm_currentdate && cat /tmp/test`

Answer (score 1):

You can store it on a variable first:

```
read -r FIRST < <(exec grep -Po '(?<=PROGRAM\()[^\)]+(?=\))' /home/programs/hello_word.sh) && grep -e "$FIRST" /home/leherad/pgm_currentdate
```

#### Update 01

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for FILE in /home/programs/*; do
    read -r FIRST < <(exec grep -Po '(?<=PROGRAM\()[^\)]+(?=\))' "$FILE") && grep -e "$FIRST" /home/leherad/pgm_currentdate && echo "$FIRST"
done
```

Comment: I think you mean this: `read -r FIRST < <(exec grep -Po '(?<=PROGRAM\()[^\)]+(?=\))' /home/programs/hello_word.sh) && grep -qe "$FIRST" /home/leherad/pgm_currentdate && echo "$FIRST"`

Comment: But now suppose that I want to do it with all the files of the folder: `/home/programs/*`. Your solution won't work.

Comment: So for every file in `/home/programs/*`, a match should be printed?

Comment: @JohnDoe Please see update and tell me what's missing or should be corrected on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a straightforward way to solve this is to use a function.

Also, your grep pattern will match shell comments, which could cause unexpected behavior in your xargs command when there are more than one matches; you might want to take steps to only grab the first match.  It's hard to say without actually seeing the input files, so I'm guessing this is either ok or comments are actually the expected place for your target pattern.

Anyway, here's my best guess at a function that would work for you.

```
get_program() {
  local filename="$1"
  local program="$( grep -m1 -Po '(?<=PROGRAM\()[^\)]+(?=\))' "$filename" )"
  if grep -q -e "$program" /home/leherad/pgm_currentdate; then
    echo $program
    grep -e "$program" /home/leherad/pgm_currentdate
  fi
}

get_program /home/programs/hello_word.sh
```

Comment: To make this work for multiple files you would add this: `for x in /home/programs/*; do get_program $x; done`